# ASP.NET MVC - Why doesn't my view inherits properly from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of T)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance

It should be possible to use generics here and pass the class-type of the Model. However this is not accepted by Visual Studio 2008:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of IEnumerable(of MyNamespace.MyClass))" %>
```

I get the following validation-error (underlined in VS):   `'Context' is not a member of 'ASP._views___home___index__asp'`

I get the following runtime error: `BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP._views___home___index__asp'.`

Note, I am using Visual Basic.NET - but that shouldn't impact the issue.

Here are some screenshots of the views & controllers, I hope somebody sees what's going on (TestClass is a simple class with ID and Name property):

- [View](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/6315/viewq.jpg) (list, model = IEnumerable)
- [View](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/5479/viewindex.jpg) (index, no model)
- [Controller](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/9941/controllerl.jpg)
- [Resulting page at runtime](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4651/runtime.jpg) (list: error)
- [Resulting page at runtime](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2261/runtimeindex.jpg) (index: works)

The solution, as per [Maik Koster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108919/maik-koster) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897497/53236) below, is:

1. Re-referencing System.Web.Mvc (had it in GAC, went back to local-copy)
2. Re-created view from Controller. Right-click controller action -> Create view... and modify from there

Now the views in an ASP.NET MVC project the page directive has an inherits attribute as follows:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was either caused by a missing reference, or was caused using a repository pattern and having implemented `IDisposable`.

For the latter scenario I added the namespaces: `System.Data.Objects` and `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses`. Next I added `System.Data.Entity` as a reference and also  added it to the list of assemblies in web.config using

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

After doing so this strange error disappeared. So you might want to check your references.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyClass>>" %>
```

Comment: Sorry the page language is VB. This is C# syntax

Comment: The site builds with this syntax, however at runtime: BC30205: End of statement expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Helpers.PaginatedList<MyProject.Models.Person>>" %>
```

Hope you got.

Comment: Sorry the page language is VB. This is C# syntax

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=104071&wa=wsignin1.0#details) in visual studio intellisense. I have the same that inherited members are underlined in designer but I didn't got a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in MVC1. I change the namespace for my model and forgot to update the view. I updated the view and the errors went away.