# Why does MVC 3 Scaffolding cause issues if the Entity Framework model is in a separate project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Whenever I try to use scaffolding with EF in MVC 3 (razor) where the datacontext is in another project I run into problems. The scaffolding process completes as expected and creates the controller and view just fine, but when I run the application I get the following error:

'ViewData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I've tried creating a completely fresh solution with nothing but the bare bones project templates and I still the get the same thing. What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem thanks to this post.

[ASP.NET MVC - Why doesn't my view inherits properly from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of T)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852585/asp-net-mvc-why-doesnt-my-view-inherits-properly-from-system-web-mvc-viewpage)

Scaffolding was really just a red herring in this case because the actual issue was just having a strongly typed view using an EntityObject.  Adding the assembly to the web.config as stated in the answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same and it worked fine or me.. check these (but these are unlikely to happen)

1. You correctly select the right view object and context
2. verify the model object's access level